# How to prevent data labels from overflowing in AmCharts?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

When adding data labels to a column chart and the columns span until the top of the chart the data labels will overflow the chart and be partially invisible.

One of the things that helps is adding some padding to the chart, but we are dealing with variable data and the end-user can set font-sizes for the label in our application, so adding fixed padding won't solve the issue in all cases.

Minimal example:

```
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.maskBullets = false;

chart.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 1999
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122
}];

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";

var valueLabel = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
valueLabel.label.text = "{valueY}";  
valueLabel.label.dy = -12;
```

Here is the example in action: https://codepen.io/geertp/pen/OJLxEKx

Is there a way to make sure the data labels in the chart are always fully visible?